# How to parse big data (XML) in GWT

Tags: java, xml, gwt

In my GWT application I am retrieving the XML data from a REST server. I am using Piriti XML parser https://code.google.com/p/piriti/wiki/Xml for deserializing the object and display in a table. As long as we are returning upto 1000 records everything is fine but with the big result it just hang and gives user message to stop the java script running in the back. Could someone please help me to find the best way to handle big data in GWT OR more precisely the best approach to parse big XML file in GWT.

Thanks a lot for all your suggestions.

Comment: Is it possible to create a paged table and only use some of the data at a time? [GWT CellTable example](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable)

Comment: Yes I am creating paged table but the actual problem is occuring intializing the data provider because that is where xml parser is converting records into list

Comment: No user needs thousands of records in a table. You should only pass one page of results to the client (i.e. data provider). When a user requests a second page, you pass the second page of results, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that parsing a big XML document slows down the browser. And you need enough memory to hold the whole DOM plus your mapped objects in memory. The only solution is to avoid such situation. You have to adapt your REST service to be able to send only small chunks of data to the browser. So if you already have a paged table you only retrieve the data for the first page at the beginning. If the user wants to change the page you do another REST call to retrieve the data for the next page.

If you cannot change the the REST service itself you can create another server side service (on a server controlled by you) as a proxy. At first access you call the original REST service, store the XML at your own server and allow the client to retrieve only parts of that XML.

Comment: very well said, thank you very much. Could you please give me any example or link for such tutorial.

Comment: Hm, sorry, I'm afraid that there is no tutorial for this exact problem. But you can break it down to several simple subproblems and find a tutorial for each one. It should not be too complicated. And if you come in trouble then you can ask here for help to that specific problem.