# Is there any SAX based parser for GWT

Tags: java, xml, parsing, gwt

I have tried to find any SAX based parser for GWT but could not find any. Does anyone know if there is any such parser exists. The reason for asking is that my server return huge xml file and I literally hang the browser while parsing using Piriti parser. Which I think is based on DOM.

https://code.google.com/p/piriti/wiki/Xml

Answer (score 1):

No, for the reasons given here http://tinyurl.com/lxr5lw2 there's none, it'd make little sense.

- do all the processing on the server and only send the relevant XML to the client
- send JSON instead of XML because that's what JavaScript understands "natively"

I believe [I'm not the only one telling you that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21412375/131929) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is performance, I would give a try to [gwtquery](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery). It is able to handle a XML string and convert it into a native browser xml object, so as you can use CSS selectors (and xpath in certain browsers) for traversing the document and reading/modifying almost everything.

gQuery [databinding](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/DataBinding#XML) can transform xml documents into POJOs, it does not handle all XML capabilities but almost of them.

Parsing, transversing, reading and writing is done using native browser calls, so you shouldn't have big performance issues with large documents, but of course you could have if the document is huge (in this case consider splitting it in server side).